# How do I use the __DIR__ constant?

Tags: php, directory

I have a problem understanding how to use  **DIR** constant

Here is the code of the file main.php  . It works well

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['firstname'])){
    include __DIR__ .'/../../form.html.php';
}else {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

    if ($firstname =='Kevin' && $lastname == 'Yank'){
    $output = 'Welcom, Oh glorious leader!';
} else {
    $output = 'Welcome to our website, ' .htmlspecialchars($firstname, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') .' ' . htmlspecialchars($lastname, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '!';

}

include __DIR__ .'/../welcome.html.php';
}
?>
```

Here is the code for  form.html.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Enter your name </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">

 </head>

 <body>
  <form method="POST" action="">
   <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"id="firstname" />

    <label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname"id="lastname" />

    <input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for  welcome.html.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Form Example </title>
  <meta charset=""utf-8">
</head>

 <body>
    <p><?php echo $output;?></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

If I understand correctly, the **DIR** "knows"  where the including file is located so that if I move the file to a new directory it should work without updatind the code.
Yet, when i created a newdirectory and i cut and pasted the file there. I didn't work

I got these messages:

> Warning:
>   include(C:\wamp\www\PracticePhP\templates\PHPPRA\STILL/../../form.html.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\PracticePhP\templates\PHPPRA\STILL\main.php on line 3

And

> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'C:\wamp\www\PracticePhP\templates\PHPPRA\STILL/../../form.html.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\wamp\www\PracticePhP\templates\PHPPRA\STILL\main.php on line 3

Line 3 is where the 1st include is.

I work on wamp at home.
It isn't a problem of pesmissions
How do i take advantage of `__DIR__ constant` if it fails to work when i move the including file to a new directory?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: `__dir__` contains the path of the file, where it was written inside. That has nothing to do with the include_dir

Comment: You do not need that constant to include other files, that is typically done by either _relative_ paths or by autoinclusion.